# Uncaught exception with qunit and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, unit-testing, qunit

I'm facing an issue while trying to get javascript unit tests to work at the command line using qunit.

Here's some sample code to reproduce the error:

file **util.js**:

```
function abc() {
    return 'abc';
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = {
        abc: abc
    };
}
```

file **util-tests.js**

```
var qunit = require("qunit");

test("Test abc function", function () {
         equal(util.abc(), 'abc');
});
```

With these files, I can run tests using the following command (gives a table-like output in the shell with the test results):

```
qunit -c util:util.js -t util-tests.js
```

Now it breaks if I add the following to util.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* some code here */
});
```

Here's the error output:

```
qunit -c util:util.js -t util-tests.js

Testing /home/mfrere/jstst/util.js ... [Error: Uncaught exception in child process.]
```

same problem with:

```
var a = $;
```

or:

```
var a = document;
```

So this makes me think that I need to import jQuery somehow, so I thought about adding jquery.js as a dependency to the command, like this:

```
qunit -c util:util.js -t util-tests.js -d jquery.js
```

The above command gives me the same 'Uncaught exception' error, even if util.js doesn't contain any reference to '$'.

I'll probably need to do something else to get qunit to recognize 'document' as well, but I don't know what or how.

Now here's my question: *what should I do to get this to work?* It is important to keep in mind I want to test my files at the command line, not in a browser.

Just in case I did something wrong in the setup process, this is how I installed node/qunit (under ubuntu):

```
git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
```

in .bashrc, I added the following line:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

picked a specific version of node

```
nvm install v0.9.2
nvm alias default 0.9
```

and installed qunit

```
npm install -g qunit
```

finally I had to add this in .bashrc as well:

```
export NODE_PATH=~/.nvm/v0.9.2/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't imported jQuery:

`$ = require('jquery'),
jQuery = require('jquery');`

If you're using browserify, change that to 'jquery-browserify'.

Comment: OK, this is what I did:
`npm install -g jquery` at the command line
then I tried adding your code to the test code without success (still Uncaught error...).
However, if I add `$ = require('jquery')` to the production code and avoid using `$(document).ready()` and use `$(function () {});` instead, my test does work. However I can't use this solution as 
1)it modifies the production code.
2)it redefines $ in the production code.
I tried writing that line in a separate file and adding it using the '-d' option, but got that 'Uncaught error' once again

Comment: Do you have that require statement in `util.js`? You need it anywhere you reference `$`.

Comment: Yes Eric, that's what I meant by the production code. I can't do that as $ would be reassigned with the jquery package I got using npm (jQuery 1.8.3) instead of the one I have installed on the production server (jQuery 1.9.1). Also I don't like having to add any test-related code to the production code. Thanks for the initial answer though, it helped me understand this problem a little better. If no answer comes in the next few days, I'll probably have to switch to browser based tests. I'd rather not, but it seems that it would give me more control over the tests themselves.

Comment: I think switching to browser-based tests is a very good idea, actually. I test all of my browser code in real browsers (many at a time, actually) using the `grunt-saucelabs` grunt task. See [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) and [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com). Bonus - you can see recorded video of the browser tests passing, (or failing) in the browser environment, and even test mobile browsers.

Node is great, but not for everything.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as no one else could give me a better one. Thanks Eric.